# SQL Server : returning a cost based on a date range between 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, date

I have 2 tables, one for transactions of inventory and one for standard cost history. I am trying to get the standard from the cost table by using the dates to determine what standard to select between the 2 tables.

So as an example:

```
ProductID   Trans.Date
-----------------------
P001        12/26/2017
P001        10/8/2018
P001        12/17/2018
P001        1/2/2019

ItemID  EffectiveDate   Standard
---------------------------------
P001    12/23/2017         50
P001    12/31/2018         52
P002    12/23/2017        100
P002    12/31/2018        103
```

My subquery is:

```
(SELECT 
     SUM(c305.t_tvat_1)
 FROM 
     tticpr305100 c305      
 WHERE 
     c305.t_item = w112.t_item 
     AND c305.t_indt <= w112.t_trdt) AS 'STD.COST'
```

Where `tvat_1` is the total value of materials, labour and other costs, and `t_item = PRODUCT ID`

What I want to see:

```
ProductID   Trans.Date  STD_Cost
---------------------------------
P001        12/26/2017     50
P001        10/8/2018      50
P001        12/17/2018     50
P001        1/2/2019       52
```

What I am seeing:

```
ProductID   Trans.Date  STD_Cost
---------------------------------
P001        12/26/2017     50
P001        10/8/2018      50
P001        12/17/2018     50
P001        1/2/2019      102
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is a `CROSS APPLY`

Not sure if the column name is [Trans.Date]  or [Date] in the trans table.

In the example below, T1 is your first table displayed, and T2 is the second table displayed.

**Example [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=67c4ec5c6a8cde6116474480f908eb5f)**

```
Select A.*
      ,STD_Cost = B.Standard
 From  T1 A
 Cross Apply (
              Select Top 1 *
               From  T2
               Where TemID=A.ProductID and EffectiveDate<=[Trans.Date]
               Order By EffectiveDate Desc
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ProductID   Trans.Date  STD_Cost
P001        2017-12-26  50.00
P001        2018-10-08  50.00
P001        2018-12-17  50.00
P001        2019-01-02  52.00
```

**Note:**  Use `OUTER APPLY` if you want to see NULL values

Comment: worked thank you John. Not used to using Cross/Outer apply. I tend to use sub-queries

Comment: @MikeMirabelli Happy to help.

Comment: @MikeMirabelli The CROSS or OUTER APPLY allow for lateral queries